# Change the suffix of column name after merging

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am merging two datasets using join commands however, I get .x & .y as the suffix of merged dataframe.

Required output is to have "_1" & "_2" as the suffix in the final merged dataframe.

Example using mtcars what I am trying

```
mt2 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var="id")

  mt2 %>% 
  inner_join(mt2, by="id") %>% 
  head()
```

Output of column name

```
id, mpg.x, cyl.x ...... mpg.y, cyl.y
```

Required output

```
id, mpg_1, cyl_1........mpg_2, cyl_2
```

Comment: Though Why python tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close to get this done (If I understood your question right)

Just try suffix argument from join function (from dplyr package)

```
library(dplyr)
data("mtcars")
mt2 <- mtcars %>% 
rownames_to_column(var="id")

mt2 %>% 
inner_join(mt2, by="id",suffix=c("_1","_2")) %>% 
names() %>% 
  dput()
```

Output of column names

```
    c("id", "mpg_1", "cyl_1", "disp_1", "hp_1", "drat_1", "wt_1", 
"qsec_1", "vs_1", "am_1", "gear_1", "carb_1", "mpg_2", "cyl_2", 
"disp_2", "hp_2", "drat_2", "wt_2", "qsec_2", "vs_2", "am_2", 
"gear_2", "carb_2")
```